# WPF: How to speed up a storyboard animation?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a storyboard animation, I'd like for it to go twice as fast how can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Storyboard SpeedRatio="2" ...>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean what i think you mean, you just have to set the [`Duration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.duration.aspx). See the [`Storyboard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.aspx) class for more information.

Comment: whoever vote me down, i would like to know why. Maybe i really got smth wrong, but in that case, please comment! Thanks.